# Socket connection failed

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, winsock

I am network integrating some code from my tester winforms applications to wpf application. The code involves calling an Connection function(which will connect to a different network) from my application. The object houses the connection routines is inside a COM component which i registered using regsvr32.  The problem is that the Connection is failing from the wpf code, the same line of code is working without any flaw in my tester app. I tried replacing the app.config of my wpf application in the tester app to confirm the problem is not happening because of any conflict inside the config file. Still the testing application worked perfectly. I checked the event viewer and following information was available.

I checked the params and everything is passed correct.

> The description for Event ID 10049
>   from source
>   ComConnect::ConnectToServer cannot be
>   found. Either the component that
>   raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the
>   installation is corrupted. You can
>   install or repair the component on the
>   local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another
>   computer, the display information had
>   to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included
>   with the event:
>
> Socket Open Failed 10049 7U 10211,
>   Entry Point

Can somebody help me debugging the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the tester app located on a different machine, connecting to a different machine?

Comment: the tester app an my wpf application is located in same machine. they are connecting to a server in different country. In that the tester app works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect to external network? Maybe the firewall is blocking the connection.

Comment: no, the demo app i created and tested in the same machine is working without any glitch.